# FCM admin sdk sendToTopic not received by everyone

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK on my backend server to create topics, subscribe/unsubscribe tokens, and send topic messages.

There are some devices, which doesn't receive messages sent to a given topic.

What I know:

- The device must be subscribed to the topic, as when I send topic message from the `firebase` console, it arrives.
- The Admin SDK-s `sendToTopic` function must work, as other devices subscribed to the topic receive the message.

I guess the problem is specific with some devices and it fails during the sending process.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?
Can I somehow see logs or any information about message status per device?

Comment: Are the client devices Android, iOS,or both?